# Connect the dots in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, interpolation, vlookup, lookup

## TLDR

I want to do the equivilent of an Excel VLOOKUP in pandas.
The unique thing about this question is that the exact values I am looking up do not exist.
I want to do a linear interpolation to look up the *nearest* value, so the usual `.map` approach does not work.

## Question

I have a pandas series, with columns `x` and `y`.

I have another pandas dataframe, with many different values of `x`, and I want to map the first dataframe to the second.
The problem is that `x` is continuous. There are many `x` values in the second dataframe which aren't in the first.
So if I do the usual approach of `df2['y'] = df2['x'].apply(df1.set_index('x')['y'])`, I'll get key errors (or NaNs).
I want to do lookup with interpolation. How do I do that?

## MWE

### Steps to reproduce:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# generate the dots that we want to lookup
# this is just a sin wave for this example
# my real data doesn't match a nice arithmatic curve
x1 = np.arange(0.0, 2.0, 0.1)
y1 = 1 + np.sin(2 * np.pi * x1)
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'x': x1, 'y': y1})

plt.plot(df1['x'], df1['y'], 'x-', label='reference', c='blue')

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'x': np.arange(0.0, 2.0, 0.06)})

# Now apply df1 as a function
# df2['y'] = f(df2['x'])
# This is the bit I don't know how to do
# this code is close, but not good enough
# and also not flexible enough since it assumes df1['x'] is evenly spaced
df2['y'] = (df2['x'] - (df2['x'] % 0.1)).map(df1.set_index('x')['y'])

plt.scatter(df2['x'], df2['y'], label='fitted', c='red')

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

### Current output:

[image: Graph of dots near and on sin wave]

### Desired Output:

I want the red dots to be shifted vertically, so that they lie on the blue curve.

i.e. replace

```
df2['y'] = (df2['x'] - (df2['x'] % 0.1)).map(df1.set_index('x')['y'])
```

with something like:

```
df2['y'] = df2['x'].something(df1.set_index('x')['y'])
```

Comment: vlookup in Pandas or SQL is in zone of merge and joins. Have you look at `.merge_asof`: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html

Comment: Hi, I am a bit confused about your problem statement. Both of your `y` in df1 and df2 come from the same function `f = lambda x: 1 + np.sin(2 * np.pi * x)`. You may not be plotting it properly, but every value of y lies on this curve for every value of x that you input. Isnt that what you already wanted?

Comment: Your plotting is the issue here, not your code. I have shown a simpler version of your code with the necessary modifications to show you the plot.

Comment: `merge_asof` looks like what I want. I'll investigate and update if I can find a solution with it.

Comment: Dont think `merge_asof` will work for you after understanding your problem. Do check my solution. I have mentioned why as well as an alternate using `pd.interpolate`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you have a set of points that come from an underlying function. You have to now interpolate some intermediate points using the same underlying function.

So, points at 0.1 distance come from a given function. You want to now find the approximate values for points at 0.06 distance such that they come from that same underlying function.

Here is what you can do.

1. Lets assume your 0.1 points come from the function `f(x)`
2. Now, lets get points at 0.06 distance with `nan` values and combine these with the 0.1 points.
3. Next lets sort all of them by value of x.
4. Now you have a sequence of points where 0.1 are filled with values from `f(x)` and 0.06 are filled with `Nan`.
5. You can simply use `pd.interpolate()` to fill the distribution and then separate the 0.06 points.

```
x1 = np.arange(0.0, 2.0, 0.1)
x2 = np.arange(0.0, 2.0, 0.06)

def f(x):
    return 1 + np.sin(2 * np.pi * x)

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A':'x1', 'x':x1, 'y':f(x1)})  #dataframe with filled values
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A':'x2', 'x':x2, 'y':np.nan}) #dataframe with nans

df3 = pd.concat([df1, df2]).sort_values('x')  #Vertically combine and sort values
df3 = df3.set_index('x').interpolate('index').reset_index()
df3 = df3[df3['A'] != 'x1'] # drop the rows which aren't in df2

#Plot all 3
plt.plot(df1['x'], df1['y'], 'x-', label='reference', c='green')  #original function
plt.scatter(df1['x'], df1['y'], label='original', c='blue')  # points at 0.1
plt.scatter(df3['x'], df3['y'], label='fitted', c='red') #interpolated points at 0.06
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image: graph of dots on sin wave]

> **NOTE:** The `blue` points are the 0.1 distance points that come directly from the `green` function. The `red` points are the 'intermediate' points at 0.06 distance which have to be interpolated. As the curve shows, the interpolation does well.
>
> You can try other methods of interpolation by changing parameter `method` (maybe try cubic spline!). Check the following link for [details](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.interpolate.html).

---

I dont think `pd.merge_asof` will solve what you need because its just for mapping based on nearest values -

```
df2 = pd.merge_asof(df1, df2, on='x', direction='nearest')
print(df2)
```

```
      x       y_x       y_y
0   0.0  1.000000  1.000000
1   0.1  1.587785  1.587785
2   0.2  1.951057  1.587785
3   0.3  1.951057  1.951057
4   0.4  1.587785  1.587785
5   0.5  1.000000  1.587785
6   0.6  0.412215  1.000000
7   0.7  0.048943  0.048943
8   0.8  0.048943  0.048943
9   0.9  0.412215  0.048943
10  1.0  1.000000  1.000000
11  1.1  1.587785  1.000000
12  1.2  1.951057  1.587785
13  1.3  1.951057  1.951057
14  1.4  1.587785  1.951057
15  1.5  1.000000  1.587785
16  1.6  0.412215  0.412215 #<--- Same value mapped!
17  1.7  0.048943  0.412215 #<--- Same value mapped!
18  1.8  0.048943  0.048943
19  1.9  0.412215  0.412215
```

It doesn't interpolate from the underlying distribution. It simply maps values and sets them to nearest based on the distance between the 2 x points. So, for 1.6 the value was 0.412215.

However, for values 1.6 to 1.7, all values are now set to 0.412215. If you are using interpolation, it would approximate the values such that 1.61 will have a different value than 1.65 and 1.68.

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: This doesn't solve my question. Sorry I wasn't clear. You can't use `f()` directly, because that doesn't really exist. I made it up when creating the MWE. For my real data, there is no known function that relates x and y. All I have is `df1`, with emperical measurements relating the two. *That's* what I want to apply.

Comment: So you want to fit a function to the points? is that what you mean? So you have a set of points at 0.1 distance. You want to map points at 0.06 distance such that they lie on the same underlying function that fits the 0.1 points?

Comment: Yes, that's what I want

Comment: ok great. so, what you need it 1. Fit a polynomial to the points with 0.1 and then use that function to estimate the points at 0.06. `merge_asof` does only an approx join between 2 columns based on some tolerance. I am not sure if that is what you need.

Comment: Updated my answer. Do check.

Comment: Looks good! I just modified the answer because the default interpolation seemed to be off a bit. I think it assumes each red dot is midway between each blue dots. e.g. when there happens to be an x in `df2` which is present in `df1`, it's `y` was not equal to the one in `df1`. I think this solution is good now.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`merge_asof`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html) with `direction='nearest'`:

```
df2 = pd.merge_asof(df1, df2, on='x', direction='nearest')
```

[image]

Comment: This is an improvement, but still not quite what I want. I edited your answer to show the graph. The red dots are now closer to the blue, but still not on the blue.
`merge_asof` rounds each `x` in df2 to the nearest `x` in `df1`. That's an improvement over rounding down like I did. However it's still not interpolation.